# Extract all the values in jsonb into a row

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm using postgresql 11, I have a jsonb which represent a row of that table, it's look like

```
{"userid":"test","rolename":"Root","loginerror":0,"email":"superadmin@ae.com",...,"thirdpartyauthenticationkey":{}}
```

is there any method that I could gather all the "values" of the jsonb into a string which is separated by ',' and without the keys?

The string I want to obtain with the jsonb above is like

```
(test, Root, 0, superadmin@ae.com, ..., {})
```

I need to keep the ORDER of those values as what their keys were in the jsonb. Could I do that with postgresql?

Comment: Note that the JSONB type does not preserve the keys order so, in fact, you could to get something like `(superadmin@ae.com, test, Root, 0, ..., {}})` instead.

Comment: (Following your latest edit): I thought maybe `jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_path_query_array(js, '$.keyvalue()')) WITH ORDINALITY` could help, but it doesn't [keep the order either](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7BrVcNJhAwCS9RTYiVzszp/2). Your best bet might be a `plv8` function at this point.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `jsonb_populate_record` function (assuming your json data does match the `users` table). This will force the text value to match the order of your users table:
**Schema (PostgreSQL v13)**

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  userid text,
  rolename text,
  loginerror int,
  email text,
  thirdpartyauthenticationkey json
)
```

---

**Query #1**

```
WITH d(js) AS (
  VALUES
      ('{"userid":"test", "rolename":"Root", "loginerror":0, "email":"superadmin@ae.com", "thirdpartyauthenticationkey":{}}'::jsonb),
      ('{"userid":"other", "rolename":"User", "loginerror":324, "email":"nope@ae.com", "thirdpartyauthenticationkey":{}}'::jsonb)
)
SELECT jsonb_populate_record(null::users, js),
       jsonb_populate_record(null::users, js)::text AS record_as_text,
       pg_typeof(jsonb_populate_record(null::users, js)::text)
FROM d
;
```

| jsonb_populate_record | record_as_text | pg_typeof |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (test,Root,0,superadmin@ae.com,{}) | (test,Root,0,superadmin@ae.com,{}) | text |
| (other,User,324,nope@ae.com,{}) | (other,User,324,nope@ae.com,{}) | text |

---

Note that if you're building this string to insert it back into postgresql then you don't need to do that, since the result of `jsonb_populate_record` will match your table:

**Query #2**

```
WITH d(js) AS (
  VALUES
      ('{"userid":"test", "rolename":"Root", "loginerror":0, "email":"superadmin@ae.com", "thirdpartyauthenticationkey":{}}'::jsonb),
      ('{"userid":"other", "rolename":"User", "loginerror":324, "email":"nope@ae.com", "thirdpartyauthenticationkey":{}}'::jsonb)
)
INSERT INTO users
SELECT (jsonb_populate_record(null::users, js)).*
FROM d;
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #3**

```
SELECT * FROM users;
```

| userid | rolename | loginerror | email | thirdpartyauthenticationkey |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test | Root | 0 | superadmin@ae.com | [object Object] |
| other | User | 324 | nope@ae.com | [object Object] |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: I won't insert the string back into my table. Actually, I would insert the aggregated string into a varchar column of another table, so it has nothing to do with the original table where the record came from.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `jsonb_each_text()` to get a set of a text representation of the elements, `string_agg()` to aggregate them in a comma separated string and `concat()` to put that in parenthesis.

```
SELECT concat('(', string_agg(value, ', '), ')')
       FROM jsonb_each_text('{"userid":"test","rolename":"Root","loginerror":0,"email":"superadmin@ae.com","thirdpartyauthenticationkey":{}}'::jsonb) jet (key,
                                                                                                                                                           value);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=0e4496325188e1dd807d4ce392a19b25)

You didn't provide DDL and DML of a (the) table the JSON may reside in (if it does, that isn't clear from your question). The demonstration above therefore only uses the JSON you showed as a scalar. If you have indeed a table you need to `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` and `GROUP BY` some key.

---

Edit:

If you need to be sure the order is retained and you don't have that defined in a table's structure as @Marth's answer assumes, then you can of course extract every value manually in the order you need them.

```
SELECT concat('(',
              concat_ws(', ',
                       j->>'userid',
                       j->>'rolename',
                       j->>'loginerror',
                       j->>'email',
                       j->>'thirdpartyauthenticationkey'),
              ')')
       FROM (VALUES ('{"userid":"test","rolename":"Root","loginerror":0,"email":"superadmin@ae.com","thirdpartyauthenticationkey":{}}'::jsonb)) v (j);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=722bc72dfcc87ab0b341406b7d528dda)

Comment: I just realized that both our solutions do not preserve the key order (which wasn't really a requirement in the question, but generating the string with the keys in a unspecified order probably isn't all that useful :)).

Comment: That's true, I tried the 2 solutions, and found both of these don't keep the key order, but it's necessary for me to keep the order as what they are, since the result string doesn't contain any key, so I could only tell the values by their ORDER. Can the method be revised to keep the order?

Comment: @Alanight: See the edit. Or go with the neat trick Math's answer provides.

Comment: BTW `concat('(', concat_ws(', ', j->>'userid', j->>'rolename', j->>'loginerror', ...), ')')`

Comment: @Abelisto: Oh yeah, that's definitely some improvement. Thanks!